# How to plot the Lorenz curve in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot Lorenz curve for the given pdf

```
L=function(x,a,l,b)
{
  term1=exp(-l*x-(b*x)^a)
  term2=a*l*(b*x)^a
  term3=a*b*(1+l)*((b*x)^(a-1))
  term4=(l^2)*(1+x)
  pdf=(term1/(1+l))*(term2+term3+term4)
  return(pdf)
}
```

Given a=l=b=1. Can anyone help to do this in R.

CDF is given by

```
Cdf=function(x,a,l,b)
{
  term5=(1+l+l*x)/(1+l)
  cdf=1-term5*term4
  return(cdf)
}
```

Comment: For those interested in a definition: https://perso.amse-aixmarseille.fr/lubrano/cours/Lecture-4.pdf : `L(p) = (1/mu) int_0^p F^{-1}(t) dt`

Comment: @Ben Bolker  please provide as answer. Maybe with an example! Many thanks!

Comment: That's not an answer, just as a definition. I don't see an easy way to get the integral of the quantile distribution ... if I did I would post it.

Comment: Already tried `curve(L(x, a=1, l=1, b=1))`?

Comment: This CDF does not depend on a and b. Is it normal?

Comment: And what is the support of the PDF?

Answer (score 4):

Your PDF is `f(x) = e^(-2*x)/2 * (3+2*x)`. It is defined on `(0, infinity)` (I checked the integral with Wolfram). We will need its average which is 5/8 (=`0.625`) according to Wolfram.

Wolfram also provides the CDF (which is not the one you give):

```
F(x) = -e^(-2*x)/2 * (x+2) + 1.
```

Wolfram also provides the solution of `F(x) = p`, that is to say the quantile function. It is

```
Q(p) = -W(4*(p - 1)/e^4)/2 - 2
```

where `W` is the Lambert `W` function.

[image]

Now we have to integrate `Q`. Again, Wolfram is successful:

[image]

Now we have everything needed.

```r
library(lamW)
H0 <- function(p) { 
  u <- 4*(p - 1)/exp(4)
  (1 - p) * (lambertWm1(u)^2 - lambertWm1(u) + 1) / (2 * lambertWm1(u)) - 2*p
}
Lorenz <- function(p) {
  (H0(p) - H0(0)) / 0.625
}

curve(Lorenz(x), from = 0, to = 1)
```

[image]

This looks like a Lorenz curve.